# how to calculate milliseconds using timeval structure?

Tags: gcc, timeval

I want to retrieve values in milliseconds from a variable of type timeval. Below is my attempt:

```
timeval* time;
long int millis = (time->tv_sec * 1000) + (time->tv_usec / 1000);
printf("Seconds : %ld, Millis : %ld", time->tv_sec, millis);

Output => Seconds : 1378441469, Millis : -243032358
```

Issue is I am getting millisecond values in minus. What is wrong with this snippets?

Comment: You didn't initialize `time`.  Or are you just missing something in your example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you did correctly initialize `time`, it's because you're overflowing when multiplying `time->tv_sec` by 1000.  In your case, it's 1.4 billion already, and the signed multiplication you're doing ends up overflowing at 2.1 billion or so.  Use 64-bit multiplication to get around it:

```
uint64_t millis = (time->tv_sec * (uint64_t)1000) + (time->tv_usec / 1000);
```

Make sure to print it out using a reasonable format.

Comment: Ya you are right. I understand its the case of overflow. but I don't know how to handle it. let me try your suggestion.