# Add or subtract an interval from a timeval

Tags: c, intervals, timeval

I've seen a number of questions / answers for subtracting two datetimes here but not one for adding or subtracting an interval to / from a timevalue.

[Add milliseconds to timeval C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491225/add-milliseconds-to-timeval-c) This asnwer does not result in a valid timeval structure.

```c
void addms2timeval(int microseconds, timeval tv); //prototype (doesn't exist yet)
...
    struct timeval later; 
    gettimeofday(&later, NULL);
    addms2timeval(1000, later);
    //later is now 1000 us in the future.
```

Also doesn't seem to be part of the standard C libraries unless I missed it.
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/systime.h.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Date-and-Time.html

Perhaps it's trivial, but it seems like one of those things that you can *think* you coded correctly but which then fails randomly every so often due to over / under flows.

Has anyone written and tested this?

Comment: what is `addmstimeval` is this you code, can we see it?

Comment: That's the point. It doesn't exist, yet... that I could find. I'm asking if someone has a function like that already. How could I have made that more clear?

Comment: so you are saying theat the code in the linked SO question doesnt work?

Comment: It works great. It just doesn't update a timeval structure. It provides an int which is the converted time plus some value. Updating a timeval structure would require dealing with overflows / underflows from the tv_ussec to tv_sec.

Comment: you cant use the modern c++ std::chrono stuff?

Comment: No. Because this is for C, not C++. I just checked, the tags are correct.

Comment: Oh, did you mean extract code from c++ std::chrono? Good idea!

Comment: my bad - I saw the c++ in the linked question.

Comment: Could use `later.tv_usec += microseconds;` and then normalize `later`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a pair of files, `timeval_math.c` and `timeval_math.h` that probably show you how to do what you want.

#### `timeval_math.h`

```c
#ifndef JLSS_ID_TIMEVAL_MATH_H
#define JLSS_ID_TIMEVAL_MATH_H

#include <sys/time.h>

extern void sub_timeval(struct timeval t1, struct timeval t2, struct timeval *td);
extern void add_timeval(struct timeval t1, struct timeval t2, struct timeval *td);
extern int  cmp_timeval(struct timeval t1, struct timeval t2);

#endif /* JLSS_ID_TIMEVAL_MATH_H */
```

#### `timeval_math.c`

```c
#include "timeval_math.h"

enum { US_PER_SECOND = 1000000 };

void sub_timeval(struct timeval t1, struct timeval t2, struct timeval *td)
{
    td->tv_usec = t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec;
    td->tv_sec  = t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec;
    if (td->tv_sec > 0 && td->tv_usec < 0)
    {
        td->tv_usec += US_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec--;
    }
    else if (td->tv_sec < 0 && td->tv_usec > 0)
    {
        td->tv_usec -= US_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec++;
    }
}

void add_timeval(struct timeval t1, struct timeval t2, struct timeval *td)
{
    td->tv_usec = t2.tv_usec + t1.tv_usec;
    td->tv_sec  = t2.tv_sec + t1.tv_sec;
    if (td->tv_usec >= US_PER_SECOND)
    {
        td->tv_usec -= US_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec++;
    }
    else if (td->tv_usec <= -US_PER_SECOND)
    {
        td->tv_usec += US_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec--;
    }
}

int cmp_timeval(struct timeval t1, struct timeval t2)
{
    if (t1.tv_sec < t2.tv_sec)
        return -1;
    else if (t1.tv_sec > t2.tv_sec)
        return +1;
    else if (t1.tv_usec < t2.tv_usec)
        return -1;
    else if (t1.tv_usec > t2.tv_usec)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

#### `addms2timeval()`

Clearly, you can write an `addms2timeval()` function, but it isn't clear to me how your interface (`void addms2timeval(int microseconds, timeval tv);` returns the value.  You should probably use one of these two interfaces:

```
struct timeval addms2timeval(int microseconds, struct timeval tv);
void addms2timeval(int microseconds, struct timeval *tv);
```

Assuming the latter, you can write:

```
void addms2timeval(int microseconds, struct timeval *tv)
{
     add_timeval(*tv, (struct timeval){.tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = microseconds}, tv);
}
```

The second argument to `add_timeval()` is a compound literal, a feature added to C99.

<sup>*This code may be used for any purpose.  There is no warranty.*</sup>