# How to properly add to timespec variables

Tags: c

I'm basically trying to set a timer to wait for a specified amount of seconds from the current time. I know that timespec's tv_sec only includes whole numbers. So I'm struggling what to do if I need to wait for 1.5 or 0.1 seconds.

Here's the bit of code I have for it:

```
struct timespec timeToWait;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeToWait);
        int rt;

        timeToWait.tv_sec += p1->intrval; //adding specified wait time
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        do{
                rt = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond,&lock,&timeToWait);
        }while (rt == 0);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

Comment: See also [Add or subtract an interval from a timeval?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71610990/15168)

Comment: BSD OSes have functions to make adding timespecs easy, btw: https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-9.2/timeradd.3

Comment: Just a sidenote: if you need to sleep for a certain duration, you should always use CLOCK_MONOTONIC, not CLOCK_REALTIME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `struct timespec` has another field called `tv_nsec` which specifies the nanosecond portion.

So if you want to wait for 1.5 seconds, add 1 to `timeToWait.tv_sec` and add 500000000 to `timeToWait.tv_nsec`.  If after doing that, `timeToWait.tv_nsec` is larger than 1000000000, then subtract 1000000000 from `timeToWait.tv_nsec` and add one more to `timeToWait.tv_sec`.

Comment: Ok. So if I don't know what the specified wait time is could I do something like:

`timeToWait.tv_nsec += (p1->interval - (int)p1->interval)*100000000` and then check if its larger than a billion?

Comment: Just tried and it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dad2theMax Recheck the zero count in `*100000000`.  Your testing may have been insufficient. `(p1->interval - (int)p1->interval)` is a dodgy way to get the fraction.  Research `trunc()`.